# How to re-render a page by calling a prop from a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think there's something about states I'm not understanding when it comes to causing a re-render. When passing a state as a prop and its setState I was expecting that I would be able to cause a re-render when calling the setState however this does not seem to be the case.

I have created a piece of code that should show what I mean. The code below holds a simple task list. You can see I have split the list into 4 parts, (header, add task, update all task, update task within a day). When you enter a task name, task time and a task day the task will be added to the task state after you press `create new task`. This will then be passed down to the second layer where the task will be sorted by day then that will passed to the final child that will list this task in a drop down which can be expanded by clicking on the small carrot on the side of the day.

My goal is try and create a system where I can update a individual task, all task associated within a certain day or all task in the list. Currently I have it where I can update all task within a day by using the `prop.setTask`. If I do something that causes a re-render like adding a new task then the child component will re-render and go where it is supposed to go but if I only change all task within a day no re-render happens despite calling my `props.setTask` and i'm not sure why since I am updating a state. Can someone explain why this is?

Please note that I have only created it to update all task within a day which you can do by selecting a day in the dropdown next to the name of the day. Each level is color coded for easier identification.

- light blue = title
- red - add task
- coral - update all task
- light grey - task within a day

Steps to reproduce issue

- CreateTask
- Open dropdown on day assigned to task
- Change task day with dropdown next to name of day
- Issue no re-render is invoked

[Example Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-hill-tmsqys?file=/src/components/WeekdayTable.js)

If you need any clarification I'm more then happy to provide it. Although I think this is just some misunderstanding with the state life cycle.

Code incase sandbox is not loading

**App.js**

```
import './styleSheets/mainPage.css';
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import AllTaskList from './components/AllTaskList'

function App() {

  const[task,setTask] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('task have updated')
    console.log(task)
  },[task])

  const clearAllTask = () =>{

    document.getElementById('task-name').value = ''
    document.getElementById('task-time').value = ''
    setTask([])

  }

  const createTask = () =>{

    let temp = {}
    let tempArr = []

    if(document.getElementById('task-name').value.length > 0 && document.getElementById('task-time').value.length > 0){

      try{
        temp.taskName = document.getElementById('task-name').value
        temp.taskTime = document.getElementById('task-time').value
        temp.taskDay = document.getElementById('task-date').value

        tempArr.push(temp)
        tempArr = task.concat(tempArr)
    
        setTask(tempArr)
      }catch{
        window.alert('It seems like you may have entered your values incorrectly please try again')
      }
  
    }else{
      window.alert('Please make sure all inputs are filled in.')
    }


  }
 
  return (
    <div className={'todo-list-all-container'}>
      <div className={'todo-list-header-container'}>
        <h className={'todo-list-all-header'}>TODO List</h>
      </div>

      <div className='todo-list-create-container'>
        <div className='todo-list-name-container'>
          <input id='task-name' placeholder='Enter Task Name' autoComplete={'off'}/>
        </div>

        <div className='todo-list-time-container'>
          <input id='task-time' placeholder='Enter Task Due Time' autoComplete={'off'}/>
        </div>

        <div className='todo-list-date-container'>
          <select name="days" id="task-date">
            <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
            <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="Wednsday">Wednsday</option>
            <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
            <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
            <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
            <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div className='create-task-button-container'>
          <button className='create-task-button' onClick={()=>{createTask()}}>Create New Task</button>
          <button onClick={()=>{clearAllTask()}} >Clear All Task</button>
        </div>

        <div className={'All-Task-List'}>
          <AllTaskList taskList = {task} setTask={setTask}/>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

export default App;

**./components/AllTaskList.js**

```
import { useState,useEffect } from "react"
import WeekdayTable from './WeekdayTable'


export default function AllTaskList(props){

    let sortedTask = {Monday:[],Tuesday:[],Wednsday:[],Thursday:[],Friday:[],Saturday:[],Sunday:[]}
    let weekDays = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednsday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
    let task = props.taskList
    let blanketTaskDay = false


    useEffect(()=>{
        sortTask()
        console.log(sortedTask)
    },[props])

    const sortTask = () =>{

        if(Array.isArray(task)){

            for(let day = 0;day < weekDays.length;day++){
                for(let taskPos = 0;taskPos < task.length;taskPos++){
                    if(task[taskPos].taskDay == weekDays[day]){
                        sortedTask[weekDays[day]].push(task[taskPos])
                    }
                }
            }

        }else{
            console.log('did not detect array')
        }

    }

    const updateAllTaskDay = (e) =>{

        blanketTaskDay = e.target.value

    }

    const resetAllTaskDay = () =>{

        blanketTaskDay = false

    }

    return(
        <div className="all-week-days-sorted">
            <div className='week-day-table-container'>
                <div className='table-container-header'>
                    <p>This Weeks Task</p>
                </div>

                <div className="update-all-container">
                    <select name="days" id="task-date" onSelect={(e)=>{updateAllTaskDay(e)}}> 
                        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                        <option value="Wednsday">Wednsday</option>
                        <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                        <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                        <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
                        <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                {weekDays.map((day)=>{
                    return <WeekdayTable 
                        weekList = {sortedTask[day]} 
                        weekDay = {day} updateDate = {blanketTaskDay} 
                        resetAllTaskDay = {resetAllTaskDay} 
                        task={props.taskList} 
                        setTask = {props.setTask}/>
                })}   

            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

**./components/WeekdayTable.js**

```
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'

export default function WeekdayTable(props){

    const[open,setOpen] = useState()
    const toggleOpen = (val) =>{setOpen(val)}

    let todaysTask = props.weekList
    let day = props.weekDay
    let masterTask = props.task

    useEffect(()=>{

        

    },[props])

    const updateAllWeekDay = (e) =>{

        let temp = []

        for(let taskPos = 0;taskPos < todaysTask.length;taskPos++){
            for(let masterTaskPos = 0;masterTaskPos < masterTask.length;masterTaskPos++){
                if(todaysTask[taskPos].taskName == masterTask[masterTaskPos].taskName && todaysTask[taskPos].taskDay == masterTask[masterTaskPos].taskDay){
                    masterTask[masterTaskPos].taskDay = e.target.value
                }
            }
        }

        props.setTask(masterTask)

    }

    return(
        <div className={'day-wrapper'}>

                <div className = {'dd-header--bold'} id={day+'-dd-header--bold'}>
                    <p>{day}</p>
                </div>
                
                <div className={'update-day'} id={day+'-update-day'} onChange={(e)=>{updateAllWeekDay(e)}}>
                    <select name="days" id="task-date">
                            <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                            <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                            <option value="Wednsday">Wednsday</option>
                            <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                            <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                            <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
                            <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
                        </select>
                </div>

                <div className='embedded-dd-header__action'>
                    <p onClick={()=>{toggleOpen(!open)}}>{open ? '^' : '⌄'}</p>
                </div>

                {open && (
                    todaysTask.map(task=>{
                        return(
                            <table>
                                <tr className={'task-val-row'}>
                                    <td className={'task-val'}>
                                        <input defaultValue = {task.taskName}></input>
                                    </td>
                                    <td className={'task-val'}>
                                        <input defaultValue = {task.taskTime}></input>
                                    </td>
                                    <td className={'task-val'}>
                                        <input id={task.taskName+task.taskDay+'-task-day'} defaultValue = {task.taskDay}/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        )
                    })
                )}

        </div>
    )

}
```

**./styleSheets/mainPage.css**

```
.todo-list-all-container{
    background-color: aqua;
}

.todo-list-header-container{
    text-align: center;

}

.todo-list-create-container{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}

.All-Task-List{
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

.table-container-header{
    display: inline-block;
}

.update-all-container{
    display:inline-block;
}

.day-wrapper{
    background-color: lightcyan;
}

.dd-header--bold{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1%;
}

.update-day{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1%;
}

.embedded-dd-header__action{
    display: inline-block;
}

.table{
    border:1px solid black;
}

.task-val-row{
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.task-val{
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Currently, the example code does not work. Can you double check?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis Thank you for letting me know I just ran the example code and saw that it was running correctly. What seemed to not be working for you? Just as a reminder that the only functional part as of now is adding a task and changing the day assigned to the task through the drop down next to that day of the week.

Comment: If you open the Example code link, you'll get "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object." Have you clicked Save on all tabs? Also, the WeekdayTable.js file is empty.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis I believe I have I just did again to be sure I wasn't aware I needed to press save on all tabs and thought the save all would cover it.

Comment: What's the function that supposed to trigger the render that doesn't happen? Are you sure that you are updating the state in that case?

Comment: If that's updateAllTaskDay, it does not update the state, hence no re-render will happen.

Comment: Also, you probably need to switch to the onChange event on the select element.

Comment: @boredProjects You should post your code inside of the question. The community doesn't need your entire source code in order to resolve a specific issue which occurs in 2-3 components.

Comment: @Dimitar I reformatted a easy to understand example of the original issue

Comment: @KostasMinaidis the issue is within the weekdayTable. There you will see updateAllWeekDay() at the end of that funciton I call props.setTask which is a prop containing the setTask() function from app.js. When I called I expected a re-render since it updated the task state created on app.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some of the fundamental rules of React are being overlooked.

- Props are meant to be used as read-only values
- Always pass a new object to the state setters
- Never mutate the state directly

Also, the `select` element has no `onSelect` event associated with it. The two available events, are `input` and `change`.

```
export default function WeekdayTable(props) {
  // ...
  let masterTask = props.task;

  const updateAllWeekDay = (e) => {

    props.setTask(masterTask); // <= You are using the same object reference 
    // as the new state, thus React will compare the previous reference
    // with the one you pass to setTask, the equality check on the previous 
    // and next state values will return true since they are the
    // same object, hence no re-render will occur

    // To trigger a re-render, you must respect the rules of React: 
    // always return a new object as a value passed to the setState methods:
    props.setTask([...masterTask])

    // Also, inside the updateAllWeekDay, you should NOT be mutating the masterTask 
    // which was passed as a prop
    // Props are meant to be treated as read-only values
    // Work on a copy of the prop, e.g.
    let masterTask = [...props.task];
    masterTask.push( something );
    etc.

  };
  ...
```

- [**Recommended reading**](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state)
- [The Select HTML Element Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#events)

Comment: Thank you for the explaing the answer and giving a reading as well!

Comment: You're welcome (to the wonderful world of React)! :)